# Implementing boundary conditions for the Biharmonic equation using $C^1$ elements.

Tags: partial-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem, finite-element-method

I am currently trying to solve the Biharmonic equation
with non-homogeneous Dirichlet boundary conditions:

$$
    \Delta^2 u = f \text{ in } \Omega, \\
             u = g \text{ on } \Gamma, \\
             \partial_\nu u = 0 \text{ on } \Gamma
$$
where $ \Gamma $ is a polygonal boundary. I am using a C^1 Hermite element that is specified by values at vertices of triangles, gradients at vertices of triangles, and the outward facing normal derivatives at each edge midpoint.

I decompose my function $ u = u_0 + u_g $ where $u_0$ vanishes on the boundary, and $ u_g $ coincides with $g$ on the boundary.
The weak formulation is given by the linear and bilinear operators

$$
a(u, v) = \int_\Omega \Delta u \Delta v dx \\
L(v) = \int_\Omega f v dx
$$
and using the decomposition of $u$, I can solve the homogeneous system

$$
a(u_0, v) = L(v) - a(u_g, v)
$$

My two questions are:

1. How do I find $u_g$? Can I interpolate it into my function space? If so, do I need to interpolate just values, or gradients as well? Or normal derivatives? Or, can I solve the weak form:
   $$
      \int_\Gamma uv dx = \int_\Gamma gv dx
   $$
   in order to find $u_g$.
2. How do I implement the modified system, given that I already have procedures for solving the homogeneous case? I haven't been able to find a single reference where this is done, If someone has any tips that would be great.

Thanks in advance for all help!

Comment: This is often considered to be one of the reasons for not using $C^1$ basis: the essential boundary conditions are hard to implement. I try to write you an extended answer later as I have implemented non-homogeneous boundary conditions for Argyris elements.

Comment: @knl Thanks so much! Looking forward to your answer! :)